# shell scripting: java program can't find property file when starting by sh

Tags: java, linux, shell, redhat

I am starting a java programm under Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5 (Tikanga).

directory structure:
 - bin ->sc.jar,start-sc.sh,sc-lib-all.jar
 - conf->log4j-sc.properties,sc.properties

command to run the java programm **(which is perfectly working)**:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../conf/log4j sc.properties -jar sc.jar -config ../conf/sc.properties
```

if i put it into a shell script the java programm can't find the prop file anymore.
shell script (start-sc.sh) looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../conf/log4j-sc.properties -jar sc.jar -config ../conf/sc.properties
```

i am a newbie on shell scripting any ideas what i am missing? thx!

Comment: A doubt that comes to my mind, sorry if it's silly: from which directory are you running the shell script? `bin` or the one containing `bin` and `conf`?

Comment: I have updated my answer; also, which properties file is not found?

Comment: the ../conf/sc.properties my programm can't find it. but its perfectly working outside of sh :/

Comment: I should have asked this first: what is the exact error message that you get running your script?

Comment: its the error message of my program, that its not possible to locate the property file.

Answer (score 0):

It sound fine to me, does this version work?

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Dlog4j.configuration=file:$(pwd)/../conf/log4j-sc.properties -jar sc.jar -config $(pwd)/../conf/sc.properties
```

Edit #1:

Try put the following before launching your program:

```
echo `pwd`
```

The output tells you where you are running your script, so you can check if it's the right path or not.

Edit #2:

Try this script

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG4JCONF="/absolute/path/to/the/log4j/conf/file"
SCCONF="/absolute/path/to/the/other/conf/file"

/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Dlog4j.configuration=file:$LOG4JCONF -jar sc.jar -config $SCCONF
```

Comment: unfortunately not. not in in shell script nor in console. pwd substitution happens!

Comment: it tells me that i am in the bin dir

Comment: My bad, remove the brackets :)

Comment: it results in the same error (can't find the file).. for some reasons the log4j-sc.properties can be found! its confusing - it somehow has to do how i read the file inside the java code :/

Comment: Is that a question or a statement? Have you discovered that the problem was in how you read that file in your Java code?

Comment: Since you are passing the parameters in the same way and one (Log4j) is retrieved, I guess you should check how you read the conf file in your program.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you started your shell script not from the bin directory, which the dir `start-sc.sh` belongs to.

to explain it clear, let's make an example.

say, your script is here:

```
/foo/bar/bin/start-sc.sh
```

if you start it under /foo/bar/bin/, it (the relative path) should work.

but if you start your script from `/home/yourHome/someDir/` , the relative path will point to `$PWD/../`, which is `/home/yourHome/`

you could either in your script first `cd  /foo/bar/bin/` before you start the java app. or do something like:

```
a=`dirname $0`
if [ $a = '.' ];then
   a=`pwd`
fi
cd $a
/usr/java/jdkxxxx/java .....
```

Comment: i am in the bin dir. if not i couldn't find the sc.jar file which is laying in the bin!